# Erro de conversão no oracle

Tags: php, oracle, pl-sql

Tenho um problema: quando executo uma `function` direto no banco não ocorre nenhum problema mas quando executo no `php`, ocorre este erro:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

o problema está na nestes if

```
IF TO_NUMBER (REPLACE(SUBSTR(VAR_STRCALCULO, 71,15), '.', ',')
```

O mais provável que esteja vindo algum valor nulo ou algo assim que não seja possível a conversão. Como tratar isso? porque não ocorre nenhum erro no banco e na aplicação sim?

Comment: bem o erro não tem segredo, a string extraída da variável VAR_STRCALCULO esta retornando algo que não é numérico. É necessário ver o que diferencia no preenchimento desta variável chamando direto de banco e por sua aplicação, provavelmente parâmetros ... Se não houver diferenças, pode fazer um teste fazendo um output (dbms_output) da variável ou gravar em uma tabela temporária para ver o que esta chegando nela.

Comment: tirei o `replace` e saiu o erro da aplicação

Comment: O possível problema seria o seu padrão de separador, que é configurado na opção de sessão NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS. Na sua aplicação deve alterar esta opção, utilizando o . como separador (Que é o padrão normalmente)

Comment: sim pode ser, vou tratar o replace na aplicação. Obrigado